# Enum of "tuples" in GraphQL to represent Languages

Tags: typescript, enums, graphql

I would like to represent many languages in my GraphQL schema using:

- Language's ISO Name
- Language's own endonym
- its ISO 639-1 code
- its ISO 639-3 code

Ideally it would look something like

```
enum Language {
  (English, English, en, eng)
  (German, Deutsch, de, deu)
  (Mandarin, 官话, zh, cmn)
  (Cantonese, 廣東話, zh, yue)
```

Because every combination of the values must be unique. However, this isn't a supported representation in GraphQL, so I thought of this kind of workaround:

```
type Language {
  isoLanguageName: ISOLanguageName!
  endonym: LanguageEndonym!
  iso639_1: ISO639_1
  iso639_3: ISO639_3
}

enum ISOLanguageName {
  English
  German
  Mandarin
  Cantonese
}

enum LanguageEndonym {
  English
  Deutsch
  官话
  廣東話
}

enum ISO639_1 {
  en
  de
  zh
}

enum ISO639_3 {
  eng
  deu
  cmn
  yue
}
```

But I'm not sold on this at all because it doesn't specify the necessary-by-definition relationships between the values.

How can I represent languages by these data in the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't have the semantics needed to define valid combinations of enums. Your types are fine as is. I suggest just creating a JSON file that contains all the language definitions and importing it as needed (unless you'd prefer this in a database table). Also recommend an `ID` for the `Language` type for caching.

To import a JSON file:

```
import languages from 'languages.json';
```

languages.json: (as an object with language codes as keys, could also be done as an array)

```
{
  "en" : {
    "isoLanguageName": "English",
    "endonym": "English",
    "iso639_1": "en",
    "iso639_3": "eng"
  },
  "de" : {
    "isoLanguageName": "German",
    "endonym": "Deutsch",
    "iso639_1": "de",
    "iso639_3": "deu"
  },
  …more languages
}
```

Comment: How would you use a JSON file for that?

Comment: that doesn't seem to constitute part of the schema then. So what should `type Excerpt { language: Language, content: String! }` actually be inthe schema?

Comment: No, the JSON is not in the schema, it is the actual data that is described by your schema. `type Excerpt { language: Language, etc… }` tells me that an `Excerpt` has a `language` *field* of type `Language` which can be expanded to reveal all the Language fields. In database terminology, excerpts are many-to-one with languages.

Comment: I think I've only just now finally understood what you're recommending to solve my problem. Use the schema from my question, and then have a hardcoded list of `Language` "instances" in the JSON file (or database I guess? why a JSON file?)

Comment: I feel like it's a shame that the valid values of the items in the JSON file cannot be specified/limited by definition of the schema. Is there any actual way to specify in the schema the limited languages that exist, and their ISO codes?

Comment: You've already done that by using enums and referring to them in your type. `type Language { isoLanguageName: ISOLanguageName! … }` says that the `isoLanguageName` must exist (!) and must be a value in the `ISOLanguageName` enum. JSON file is a mere convenience but nice for something that basically never changes.

Comment: But the schema also allows a `Language { English, Deutsch, zh, eng }` to exist

Comment: Yes that's correct as I stated right in the first sentence of the answer. A GraphQL schema is regrettably not omnipotent.